# Kronecker delta equation simplification

Tags: tensors, kronecker-product, kronecker-symbol

I am trying to simplify a tensor equation with Kronecker delta
$$  A_{ij} \big ( \delta_{ik}\delta_{jm} -\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}\delta_{km}  \big) $$
$A$ and $\delta$ are Cartesian tensors.

I know definition of Kronecker delta

$$\delta_{ij}=
\begin {cases}
0 \quad \text {if} \quad i \ne j \\
1 \quad \text {if} \quad i = j
\end {cases}
$$
and $\delta_{ii} = 3$
But I am confused how to simplify the equation. The answer at the end of simplification seems $A_{km}$. Any direction or comments?

Comment: I can't make much sense of the second term there, but $A_{ij}\delta_{ik}\delta_{jm} = A_{km}$ if we're summing in $i$ and $j$ - the Kronecker delta "collapses" sums, essentialy putting $k$ where we had $i$, and $m$ where we had $j$.

Comment: @IvoTerek You are correct. But I need to solve the second term as well. The fraction 1/3 and Kronecker delta property $\delta_{kk}=3$ might have to do something here.

Comment: ok.. well, I wrote it all, check the answer there. You sure that the indices are right on the second term, though?

Comment: @IvoTerek As per Einstein summation notation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation, $i,j$ are summed over, so must appear twice in second multiplication term of $\delta, A$. Free indices $k,m$ appear in first term, so should be in second term as well. In short, I feel the indices are correct. Looks good to you?

Comment: I thought a bit about that later, there doesn't seems to be anything wrong at all, it was my distraction earlier, probably. But the answer will be more than just $A_{km}$, the second term will not vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write sums, just for now: $$\begin{align} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}\big( \delta_{ik}\delta_{jm} -\frac{1}{3}\delta_{ij}\delta_{km}  \big) &= \sum_{i,j}A_{ij}\delta_{ik}\delta_{jm} - \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}\delta_{ij}\delta_{km} \\ &= \sum_{i,j}A_{ij}\delta_{ik}\delta_{jm} - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{km}\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}\delta_{ij} \\ &= A_{km} - \frac{1}{3}\delta_{km}(A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}),\end{align}$$so the answer is not only $A_{km}$.

Comment: Didn't you forget to multiply by $A_{ij}$ in the second sum?

Comment: Oh boy, I did. Wait a sec